# Sata drive overiding IDE?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, pata

I recently just bought a Sata Hard drive and hooked it up and installed a OS. I am making it my Primary hard drive. What I had before that though was 2 IDE hard drives that I used. One of them was my Prime and the other one was just a second to keep stuff on.

My problem is that now since I hooked up the Sata drive, my IDE drives are not being detected at all. I even tried to remove the Sata drive completely and use my IDE drives, but it couldn't be detected.

What should I do? Am I connecting them wrong?

Comment: Comment by @Shark: Must be some connection/power supply issue

Comment: Have you checked to see if your BIOS is up to date?

Answer (score 1):

Some models of PCs have this behavior, certain Dell models will disable IDE hard drives when a Sata disk is introduced into the system. This was a problem on early hybrid boards when sata first came out.

What model of PC is it?

Is the Sata on the motherboard or an add in card?